# httpd.service failed to start 403 error page on all domain and subdomain after updating apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, http-status-code-403

I recently updated apache to the latest version, and suddenly website is down 403 forbidden in all docs.

I've spent the last 6 hours tried reading everything there is on the internet, tried every command change every setting and still failed to fix this.

Any help will be really appreciated, i'm about to lose my job if i cant fix this by today

i'll show anything any conf files, i need someone who can help me through this

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any information to understand what the problem might be.
Because you updated to the latest version, the first link I suggest you to read is this one: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html